# Concatenar Observables Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

soy nuevo en Angular y estoy tratando de concatenar dos observables uno de ellos viene de un servicio API Rest, y no puedo obtener la salida que espero, solo obtengo dos renglones. Desde ya gracias.

el que viene del servicio rest es:

```
[
{"prueba_id":1,"distancia":"100"},
{"prueba_id":2,"distancia":"200"},
{"prueba_id":3,"distancia":"400"},
....
]

const sexo$ = from([{sexo: 'Masculino'}, {sexo: 'Femenino'}]);
```

La salida que espero

```
[
{"prueba_id":1,"distancia":"100","sexo": "Masculino"},
{"prueba_id":1,"distancia":"100","sexo": "Femenino"},
{"prueba_id":2,"distancia":"200","sexo": "Masculino"},
{"prueba_id":2,"distancia":"200","sexo": "Femenino"},
{"prueba_id":3,"distancia":"400","sexo": "Masculino"},
{"prueba_id":3,"distancia":"400","sexo": "Femenino"},
....
]

this.pruebaService.getPruebas().pipe(
  concatMap( (prueba: Prueba[]) => 
    sexo$.pipe(map( (sexo,i) => { return {...prueba[i], sexo: sexo.sexo}})
    )
  )
).subscribe( (rta) => { 
  console.log('JSON.stringify(rta))
},
  error => console.log("Error: " + error),
  () => console.log("Ok: ")
)
```

Comment: Tienes un atributo comun entre la llamada que devuelve las pruebas y la de los sexos o lo que quieres es generar una entrada duplicada para que por cada prueba haya dos entradas una para cada sexo?

Comment: Tal cual, lo que quiero es generar dos entradas para la misma prueba una por cada sexo.

Answer (score 1):

Con [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```
of([
    { "prueba_id": 1, "distancia": "100" },
    { "prueba_id": 2, "distancia": "200" },
    { "prueba_id": 3, "distancia": "400" }
])
    .pipe(
        switchMap(pruebas =>
            of([{ sexo: 'Masculino' }, { sexo: 'Femenino' }])
                .pipe(
                    map(sexos =>
                        pruebas.flatMap(prueba =>
                            sexos.map(({ sexo }) =>
                                ({
                                    ...prueba,
                                    sexo
                                })
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
        )
    )
```

Con [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```
of([
    { "prueba_id": 1, "distancia": "100" },
    { "prueba_id": 2, "distancia": "200" },
    { "prueba_id": 3, "distancia": "400" }
])
    .pipe(
        switchMap(pruebas =>
            of([{ sexo: 'Masculino' }, { sexo: 'Femenino' }])
                .pipe(
                    map(sexos =>
                        pruebas
                            .map(prueba =>
                                sexos.map(({ sexo }) =>
                                    ({
                                        ...prueba,
                                        sexo
                                    })
                                )
                            )
                            .flat()
                    )
                )
        )
    )
```

Si la ejecución del segundo `Observable` no depende de que la ejecución del primero haya terminado, es decir si después de la ejecución del primer `Observable` no se espera un parámetro necesario para hacer la consulta del segundo, puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
combineLatest(
    of([
        { "prueba_id": 1, "distancia": "100" },
        { "prueba_id": 2, "distancia": "200" },
        { "prueba_id": 3, "distancia": "400" }
    ]),
    of([{ sexo: 'Masculino' }, { sexo: 'Femenino' }])
)

    .pipe(
        map(([pruebas, sexos]) =>
            pruebas.flatMap(prueba =>
                sexos.map(({ sexo }) =>
                    ({
                        ...prueba,
                        sexo
                    })
                )
            )
        )
    )
```